# Google App Engine + Cloud SQL - Writing multiple times with a single call?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, nosql, google-cloud-sql, knex.js

I'm having an issue with Cloud SQL and Google App Engine writing properly. Using NoSQL with Cloud SQL and Google App Engine for writing to the DB, I've managed to get a connection - which is great!

Only problem is, when I run an insert function for the application `insertVisit(knex, visit)`, there are multiple writes for a single call. Here is all the relevant code.

**app.js**

```
//Connecting to the NoSQL Cloud SQL database, and using Knex to do all database-y things. 

const knex = connect();

function connect () {   
  const config = {
      socketPath: "/cloudsql/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>",
      user: "USERNAME",
      password: "PASSWORD",
      database: "DATABASE"
  };

  // Connect to the database
  const knex = Knex({
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: config
  });

  return knex;
}

function insertVisit (knex, visit) {
      return knex('user_visits').insert(visit);
    }
}

function getVisits (knex) {
  return knex.select().table('user_visits').pluck('visits')
}
```

**App Engine endings**

```
app.get('/new_visit', (req, res, next) => {

  // Create a visit record to be stored in the database
  const visit = {
    visits: new Date()
  }

  insertVisit(knex, visit)
    // return a response
    .then(() => {
      res
        .status(200)
        .set('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
        .send(`successfully created.`)
        .end();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      next(err);
    });
});

app.get('/see_visits', (req, res, next) => {
  getVisits(knex)
  .then( (visits) => {
    res
        .status(200)
        .set('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
        .send(`Last 10 visits:\n${visits.join('\n')}`)
        .end();
  })
})
```

I'm returning everything just fine. But when I visit `new_visit` once, and then `see_visits` I would expect a response on the webpage of, say:

```
Last 10 Visits: 

Aug 10 12:34:56 
Aug 11 23:11:45
```

Instead, I *know* double (or triple) calls are happening, because I get:

```
Last 10 Visits: 

Aug 10 12:34:56
Aug 10 12:34:57
Aug 10 12:34:57
Aug 11 23:11:45
Aug 11 23:11:46
```

Relevant **app.yaml** fields are as follows:

```
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Which are the default suggestion from Google.

Does anyone have any insights or... any knowledge about what I can do to prevent these double, triple writes from happening? It's a huge hole in the pocket if duplicate data is being written every time I try to insert more information into a table.

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is to use something like [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web), which only requires you to insert 4 lines of javascript to your frontend and will present more reliable information than a home brew solution.

If you absolutely need to do something yourself, you are going to have to pair the timestamp with an identifiable id of some kind. Otherwise, every refresh of the page is going to give you a new entry. Then when inserting into your database, use raw SQL and add `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to the end of the `INSERT` (Knex currently doesn't support this functionality via ORM - see [here](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/701).)

For what ID you use, stay away from using the IP address - folks from the same network will share an IP, which means you will dedupe visits you don't want to. Instead I would suggest generating a [UUID](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) and storing it in a cookie for the user.